# Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Tags: errors, browser-compatibility

My WP site http://kyl.fi has stopped displaying anything else than Front Page when browsing the site with IE. The problem has been confirmed by several users with several versions of IE from 9-11.

When accessing Front Page (i.e. kyl.fi/), everything works fine. But when trying to access any other page (e.g. kyl.fi/english/), user receives error "**Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage**". Btw, IE has different type of error message for 404 and 500, so this is something else.

The problem occurs only with IE. When browsing with other browsers such as Chrome and Firefox, everything is working fine.

The site was working earlier without any problems with IE as well and I haven't made any changes to anything since that testing, except that WordPress was updated from 3.9 to 3.9.1.

I have tried the basic fixes already, but without success:

- Clearing browser caches and refreshing
- Re-installing WP 3.9.1 (not manually though)
- Disabling WP plugins
- Testing with Twentyfourteen theme
- Updating permalinks
- Verifying .htaccess file is ok

Some other tests I have made:

- Tried to access resources (e.g. images) in theme's directory with direct URI - working fine
- Changed IE's user-agent to Chrome - doesn't fix the problem
- Changed Chrome's user-agent to IE - problem does not occur
- Tried to access WP admin panel with IE - working fine
- Tried to access site's pages with non-rewritten URLs (e.g. kyl.fi/?p=1891) - doesn't fix the problem

I'm running out of ideas what could cause this strange behavior. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this still happen, after you [disabled all plugins and switched to one of the Twenty* themes?](http://i.imgur.com/wScmw.png) Please follow the linked process to identify the conflicting plugin or theme.

Comment: Yes. This is not a theme or plugin related issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't actually occur with IE only, it only breaks page in IE.

Your pages have circular 301 redirect between shortlink and permalink URLs — `http://kyl.fi/ajankohtaista/` sends browser to `http://kyl.fi/?p=16`, which sends browser to `ttp://kyl.fi/ajankohtaista/` and the circle have closed.

Other browsers just decide to ignore this, ditch stupid redirect and show page anyway. IE gets confused by it and decides to not show the page received.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I don't understand why this is happening in first place. Why shortlinks have redirect to permalinks? So what is the root cause and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem! The solution: I was using a custom permalink structure `http://kyl.fi/%category%/%postname%/`. I removed the trailing slash (i.e. the last `/`) and voila. However, I'm quite sure I used a permalink structure with the trailing slash before without any problems, so I'm still confused and would be interested the hear more about this issue if somebody has an explanation. I'm using the HTML5BP .htaccess template, which has a rewrite rule to remove the trailing slashes, if that matters.